# Handle user control dropdownlist selected index change event in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ascx, selectedindexchanged

I have create the user control and add the same in aspx code behind. I want to handle the selected index change event for dropdownlist in aspx page. Kindly help me to do this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_parent" runat="server" Text="Parent Node" CssClass="control-label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_parent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>

phContactDetails.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControl/WUC_DisLabelControl.ascx"));

foreach (var control in phContactDetails.Controls)
            {
                var usercontrol = control as WUC_DisLabelControl;
                DropDownList ddl_parenrt = ((DropDownList)usercontrol.FindControl("ddl_parent"));
                ddl_parenrt.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlparent_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

protected void ddlparent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //Not Firing 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not added `SelectedIndexChanged` event on dropdown.

Add `SelectedIndexChanged="ddlparent_SelectedIndexChanged"` on dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_parent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlparent_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I have added but the first dropdown selected index change event fired. Other control event not fired